# How to create a JavaFX KeyCombination with three or more keys?

Tags: javafx, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm creating a simple text editor with *JavaFX*.
I've found out that I can add shortcuts to menu items by using

```
MenuItem.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination("Ctrl+S"))
```

I'm going to use this for the frequently used `MenuItem`s in my application, such as *Save*, *Open* etc. This works fine as long as I only use two keys, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, but I also want to create some combinations with three keys, such as for the *Save All* option, which in many programs has the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Same as for *Save*, but with an extra <kbd>A</kbd>, which logically stands for *All*).

This brings a problem.
JavaFX doesn't let me use more than two keys with the `KeyCombination.keyCombination(String)` method. I just get an error when I run the application.

I've used Google, as always, but I can't find *anything* about using more than two keys, so I decided to ask a question here.

I wonder how I can set more than two keys (I currently require three) as a shortcut for a `MenuItem` in JavaFX.

Comment: There is no quick & easy way to get `Ctrl+S+A`, but you may want to use `Shift+Ctrl+S`, which is often used for _Save All_. You can use multiple _modificator_ keys (Shift, Control, Alt, Meta) in a key combination.

Comment: @TomasMikula I guess you are right. I'll go for `Shift + Ctrl + S`. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Problem is that the [KeyEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html) only has one [KeyCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCode--).
So its not possible to let an KeyCombination match multiple KeyCodes.

But you can try something like this:

Store all pressed Keys into an List (maybe you have to use event Listener for keyPressed)

```java
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    scene.setOnKeyPressed((event) -> {
        codes.add(event.getCode());
    });
    scene.setOnKeyReleased((event) -> {
        codes.remove(event.getCode());
    });
}
```

Write your own KeyCombi class

```java
private class MultipleKeyCombi extends KeyCombination {
    private List<KeyCode> neededCodes;

    public MultipleKeyCombi(KeyCode... codes) {
        neededCodes = Arrays.asList(codes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean match(KeyEvent event) {
        return codes.containsAll(neededCodes);
    }
}
```

And use it in your Menu.

```
item.setAccelerator(new MultipleKeyCombi(KeyCode.A, KeyCode.S));
```

This should work.

I wrote a Prototype here [Bitbucket Repo](https://bitbucket.org/kogs/multiplekeycombi)

Answer (score 4):

I am also new to JavaFX, I have done the following code and it works!

```
primaryStage.getScene().getAccelerators().put(
        KeyCombination.keyCombination("CTRL+SHIFT+U"),
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Keycombination Detected");
            Platform.exit();
            }
        }
        );
```

Comment: Will  KeyCombination.keyCombination("CTRL+S+A") also work? Cause that's the problem he is facing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by simply pressing Ctrl + S at the same time you exit from the stage window.

```
primaryStage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.keyCombination("Ctrl+S"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my contribution. Basically, this capture the pressed keys and collect them into an `ObservableList<Keycode>` and remove it from the list when the key is released.

Then, on change event, it detectes the content of the identifier/ variable where the keys are stored.

Here is an example to implement it:

```
    private ObservableList<KeyCode> keys = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private void keyboardShortcuts(){

        // collect pressed key
        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (event) -> {
            if (!keys.contains(event.getCode())) {
                keys.add(event.getCode());
            }
            event.consume();
        });

        // remove pressed key when it is released   
        scene.setOnKeyReleased((event) -> {
            keys.remove(event.getCode());
            event.consume();
        });

        keys.addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            @Override
            public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
                if( keys.size() == 3 // this number is important to make sure the pressed key don't exceed the number of keys we want

                // detect control (windows) or command (mac) key pressed
                && (keys.contains(KeyCode.CONTROL) || keys.contains(KeyCode.COMMAND)) 
                && keys.contains(KeyCode.SHIFT)
                && keys.contains(KeyCode.A)){

                    System.out.println("Save As");

                }
                else if( keys.size() == 2 // this number is important to make sure the pressed key don't exceed the number of keys we want
                &&(keys.contains(KeyCode.CONTROL) || keys.contains(KeyCode.COMMAND))
                && keys.contains(KeyCode.O)){

                    System.out.println("Open");

                }
            }
        });
    }
```